# Django Tastypie posting with ForeignKey

Tags: ajax, django, post, tastypie

I am currently learning Django and Tastypie. I have looked all over for an answer, but can't seem to find anything that addresses this issue specifically.

I have defined three resources in Tastypie: User, Search and Comment. There are many comments for a search.

A simplified look at **models.py** are:

```
class Search(models.Model):
    search_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    search_slug = models.SlugField(default='')
    search_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    splunk_search = models.TextField()
    splunk_results = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    search = models.ForeignKey(Search)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment_title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

And in my **api.py**:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'

class SearchResource(ModelResource):
    comments = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.CommentResource','comments', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Search.objects.all()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        resource_name = 'search'
        serializer = urlencodeSerializer()
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    search = fields.ToOneField(SearchResource, 'search')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Comment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'comment'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = Authentication()
        serializer = urlencodeSerializer()
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=CommentForm)
```

My submit handler in **js**:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/api/v1/comment/',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: $("#commentForm").serialize(),
     processData: false,
     success: function(messages) {
     console.log("Success!");
   },
   error: function() {
     console.log("Oh no, something went wrong!");
   }
 });
```

I always get back the response: `Comment has no search.`

Also, this form works perfectly fine outside of tastypie. The original django form has excluded both the search and the author fields and their data is pre-populated. I just can't seem to make the same thing work in Tastypie. Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made `SearchResource` to have `comments` (m2m relation) but you didn't specify it in model class `Search`, so I suppose you used *reverse relationship*.

If so, instead of,

```
class SearchResource(ModelResource):
    comments = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.CommentResource','comments', null=True, blank=True)
```

change to,

```
class SearchResource(ModelResource):
    comments = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.CommentResource', 'comment_set', related_name='search', null=True, full=True)
```

The problem "comment has no search" because you didn't specify `related_name`. In another side, class `Search` has no attribute `comments` but `comment_set` (reverse relationship).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this but I keep getting a response of 'Comment has no search'.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. It was an oversight on my part. Your answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a web page with a form that you're attempting to send to tastypie.  However, your data is generated by:

```
$("#commentForm").serialize()
```

That will generate URL encoded data, but you need to send JSON.

You'll need to send the data as JSON.  This might work instead:

```
JSON.stringify($("#commentForm").serializeArray());
```

This might not work directly.  You might need to modify the result of serializeArray() into the proper format for tastypie before passing it into JSON.stringify().

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I never even considered this. I will let you know once I get a chance to try this out.